# How to get join value of 3rd level connected DB table in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, yii2

I have a main database table, which is connected over relation table - 1st table - (has many) to second table. This one is connected to third table.

When I want to receive data for second table from model for main DB table I of course do this:

```
return $this->hasMany(MySecondTable::className(), ['id_1' => 'id_1'])
            ->viaTable('mysecondTable', ['id_2' => 'id_2']);
```

That works great... So when receiving third table I need to get relation above, use field from my second table and join third table.

Is there any solution to that or do I have to build my own query?

It might be done like this (did not get it to work)

```
return $this->hasMany(MyThirdTable::className(), ['my_second_table.id_2_2' => 'id_2'])
            ->viaTable('myRelTable', ['id_r' => 'id_r'])
            ->viaTable('mysecondTable', ['id_2' => 'id_2']);
```

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7486 works for me. See the answer by cebe